# Unable to retrieve new image on webpage

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot and I am still getting the old image in my web page after I swapped the image. I have cleared my browser cache, did a maven clean install and still no difference. I even changed the entire folder name where the images are kept and yet, I am still able to get the correct images when I should be getting nothing. I have double checked and it is definitely the correct path. There is no other images folder in this project to cause any confusion.

Please refer to image. The correct folder name should be "images". Instead I changed the folder name to "images1" to test and yet I get the correct images. I don't understand what kind of caching is going on here. Please advice how to clear it.

[image]